# Kotlin listeners that are Java- and Kotlin-friendly

Tags: java, kotlin, interop

I've seen similar Q&A's but didn't find what I'm looking for - maybe I'm missing something.

I want to implement (in a Kotlin class) a listener property. The listener only has one method, so it's lambda-friendly.

```
    interface Listener {
        fun onDone(id: String)
    }

...

    class Manager {
        var listener: Listener? = null
    }
```

When I want to set this property from Java (8) code, I can do it cleanly using a lambda:

```
    manager.setListener(id -> {

    });
```

However, in Kotlin, I must create an anonymous object with a method:

```
    manager.listener = object : OfflineManager.Listener {
        override fun onDone(id: String) {
        }
    }
```

The other option, using function reference in Kotlin:

```
var listener: ((String) -> Unit)? = null
```

Allows nice lambda in Kotlin, but a Java lambda requires a return value (even though the function is defined as returning Unit) which is strange to Java developers.

So how can I get the best of both?

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is no straightforward method that allows to define such listener that is "cleanly applicable" in both Java and Kotlin. If you want to use your listener in Java, you have to stick to an interface and Kotlin doesn't support SAM conversions on Kotlin interfaces:

> [...] this feature [SAM conversions] works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported.

However you could create an extension method (this way it won't be visible as one of the `Manager`'s methods in Java) that translates given lambda into an anonymous object:

```
inline fun Manager.setListener(crossinline onDone: (String) -> Unit) {
    listener = object : Listener {
        override fun onDone(id: String) {
            onDone(id)
        }
    }
}
```

This way you could keep it pretty clean in both Java and Kotlin.

---

**Edit**:
A variation of the above:

```
class Manager {
    private var listener: Listener? = null

    fun getListener(): Listener? = listener

    fun setListener(listener: Listener?) {
        this.listener = listener
    }
}

var Manager.onDone: (String) -> Unit
    get() = getListener()?.let { it::onDone } ?: {}
    set(value) {
        setListener(
            object : Manager.Listener {
                override fun onDone(id: String) {
                    value(id)
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

In this case in Java you can still reference the listener using setter and getter (which had to be explicitly written) and the lambda-based filed is not visible in a Java's `Manager` instance. In Kotlin the `listener` variable is not visible outside the `Manager` class and it can be used as it was a lambda field.

However both `getListener` and `setListener` methods would be visible and reachable in Kotlin. Also Kotlin's lambda won't be inlined while being translated to the anonymous object.

Comment: I didn't know extension methods are hidden from Java. But even if they are, how do I hide the interface-based variant from Kotlin?

Comment: @noamtm: They are not hidden, Kotlin generates a separate Java class for them and put them inside as static methods. What I meant was that this extension won't be reachable in a Java's `Manager` class instance, so the Java developer shouldn't be aware such method even exists. I don't think you can hide the interface-based variable somewhere in Kotlin though. As I said, I find it _pretty_ clean, but still it is just a workaround.

Comment: @noamtm I've edited my answer with kind of a second approach.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, interfaces in Kotlin doesn't support SAM conversions. You can read about it for example [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770?source=post_page---------------------------).

For now, you can declare your `Listener` interface in Java:

```
public interface Listener {
    void onDone(String id);
}
```

and use it in Kotlin

```
manager.listener = Listener { println(it) }
```